# Template metaprogramming solution for calling a function with arbitrary number of arguments in O(1)

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have a table of functions, all of them returning a double but with an arbitrary number of doubles as arguments. For example:

```cpp
double sum1(double a, double b, double c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
double sum2(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    return a + b + c + d;
}
double sum3(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

And I have a table that summarizes and provides some metadata for these functions

```cpp
struct Function {
    void* fnptr;
    size_t numargs;
};
Function fntable[] = {{(void*)&sum1, 3}, {(void*)&sum2, 4}, {(void*)&sum3, 2}};
```

What I want to do is to be able to call say `sum3` with just its index and a `double*` array, and have the solution figure out to make the proper call, ie place the doubles in appropriate registers for the call.

The classic solution for this would be using a manual switch case and for each number of arguments have the call explicitly up to a maximum number say 20, perhaps with the help with macros to alleviate the typing, as shown below.

```cpp
template <size_t N, typename... Args>
struct FnType {
    using Call = typename FnType<N - 1, double, Args...>::Call;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct FnType<0, Args...> {
    typedef double (*Call)(Args...);
};

double callfn(void* fn, const std::vector<double>& args) {
    switch ( args.size() ) {
        case 0: { return FnType<0>::Call(fn)(); }; break;
        case 1: { return FnType<1>::Call(fn)(args[0]); }; break;
        case 2: { return FnType<2>::Call(fn)(args[0],args[1]); }; break;
        case 3: { return FnType<3>::Call(fn)(args[0],args[1],args[2]); }; break;
        case 4: { return FnType<4>::Call(fn)(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3]); }; break;
    };
    return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}
```

This works but I have a requirement to be able to change the maximum number of arguments arbitrarily without changing the code.

This is the driver for this feature. Everything is available on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/9xGaTG491

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        std::cout << "Usage: caller <fnum> [<value>...]" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int fnum = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    int numargs = argc - 2;
    std::vector<double> args(numargs);
    for (int j = 0; j < numargs; ++j) args[j] = std::atof(argv[j + 2]);
    Function fn = fntable[fnum];
    if (fn.numargs != numargs) {
        std::cout << "Wrong number of arguments for function #" << fnum << ". Got "
                  << numargs << " expected " << fn.numargs << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << callfn(fn.fnptr, args) << std::endl;
}
```

And this is a typical session

```bash
$ ./caller 1
Wrong number of arguments for function #1. Got 0 expected 4
$ ./caller 1 1 2 3 4
10
$ ./caller 1 10 20 30 40
100
$ ./caller 0 100 200 300 400
Wrong number of arguments for function #0. Got 4 expected 3
$ ./caller 0 100 200 300 
600
$ ./caller 2 4 5
9
```

There are a few things I am not checking as maximum function number etc but this is just a toy example.

So the question is: how to replace that switch statement with something O(1) where I can set arbitrarily the maximum number of parameters at compile time? Does metatemplate programming offer a solution?

Obviously I am not asking anyone to write my code but I would appreciate ideas.

Comment: *"I have a requirement to be able to change the maximum number of arguments arbitrarily without changing the code"* -- impossible as written, since the maximum is part of the code. I think you mean "without changing the implementation". That is, you can change the part of the code where the maximum is defined, but you don't want to change the definition of `callfn`.

Comment: I can pass the maximum number as a preprocessor parameter/macro, for example.

Comment: OK, I suppose you could define a maximum via the command line, but what does that accomplish? You'll have no functions defined that could take advantage of the new maximum. Or is this supposed to be a header-only library type of thing?

Comment: This could be part of a plugin architecture where new plugins (as eg shared libraries) define new functions and provide that metadata.  The usage is beyond the scope of this question and I agree the practicality of the example is questionable at a glance. But I can guarantee that the usefulness of this solution would have practical use for me.

Comment: Have a look at [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). They can be used to use binary operations (e.g. define the operation on two arguments) and extend it to n-aray.

Comment: I think, this is only possible if the size of `args` is known at compile time. If a tuple instead of a vector is an option for you, this can be easily unpacked to function parameters: http://aherrmann.github.io/programming/2016/02/28/unpacking-tuples-in-cpp14/

Comment: @PepijnKramer That solves the problem for each N  I feel. That is what the `FnType` is doing in the code example. But I need some sort of table to go from the `void*` to the actual call. Perhaps a vector or array of base pointers to a virtual base. I feel like I need dynamic polymorphism as well.

Comment: You may want to use technique similar to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3dao98hE4). Here, `Caller` is a class template with a `size_t` template parameter. The technique allows to call `Caller<N>()()` for any *variable* `N` up to a constant limit, or to call `Caller<M>()()` for all `M` up to a constant limit.

Comment: @n.m.  I got it play ball https://godbolt.org/z/v6ce7G49c  however the sequence yields a sequence of `N ifs` which is definitely not `O(1)`.

Comment: You can use the loop scheme to initialize an array of function pointers or object pointers once, then use the array to call the function in O(1).

Comment: @n.m. Yep that will lead to the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use type erasure to handle any size of arguments.

```
class Function
{
    struct BaseCaller
    {
        virtual ~BaseCaller() = default;
        virtual size_t numargs() const = 0;
        virtual double call(std::vector<double>) const = 0;
    };
    
    template <typename... Args>
    requires (std::is_convertible_v<Args, double> && ...)
    class Caller : public BaseCaller
    {
        double(*func)(Args...);
    public:
        explicit Caller(double(*func)(Args...)) : func(func) {}
    
        size_t numargs() const override
        {
            return sizeof...(Args);
        }
        
        double call(std::vector<double> args) const override
        {
            return [&]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
            {
                return func(args[Is]...);
            }(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
        }
    };
    
    std::unique_ptr<BaseCaller> caller;
    
public:
    
    template <typename... Args>
    requires (std::is_convertible_v<Args, double> && ...)
    Function(double(*func)(Args...)) : caller(std::make_unique<Caller<Args...>>(func)) {}
    
    size_t numargs() const
    {
        return caller->numargs();
    }

    double operator()(std::vector<double> args) const
    {
        return caller->call(std::move(args));
    }
};
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b72b3c2b2ba02272)

You can construct them at runtime thusly:

```
constexpr size_t MaxArgs = 100;

template <size_t>
using double_t = double;

template <size_t... Is>
using RawFunction = double(*)(double_t<Is>...);

Function fromVoid(void * f, size_t numargs)
{
    static auto cast = []<size_t... Js>(std::index_sequence<Js...>, void * f){ return Function(reinterpret_cast<RawFunction<Js...>>(f)); };
    static auto array = [=]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> std::array<std::function<Function(void*)>, MaxArgs>
    {
        return { [=](void * f){ return cast(std::make_index_sequence<Is>{}, f); }... };
    }(std::make_index_sequence<MaxArgs>{});
    return array[numargs](f);
}
```

[Also on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d72cbb60e78ceebf)

Comment: This does not solve the fundamental problem, which is you start with a `void*` opaque pointer and a vector. You still need a switch or table of sorts. You can see it does not integrate with the toy example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ez8qbnfdT

Comment: @HenriqueBucher I'm suggesting you throw away the code that uses a `void*` opaque pointer, and just use this

Comment: Your code as presented is not a replacement. It is a particular case. Still, that was a hard requirement set very clearly. It might be a good solution for another problem but not this one as stated.

Comment: It *is* a replacement for your function struct. https://godbolt.org/z/b54zTW7sW

Comment: That's neat but the problem is that you do not have the functions at compile time. You might load at runtime a shared library with functions with 100 arguments or more.

Comment: Aside: casting function pointers to `void *` isn't required to be value-preserving. You *can* cast to `void(*)()` instead

Comment: Your last edit made it a completely different answer which can fit nicely in the example, it seems. Let me have a look. BTW why do you `std::move` the vector? That is awfully expensive.

Comment: Im on the fence accepting this as an answer though. As you can see https://godbolt.org/z/fdaqx5aT3  it seems to be `O(N)` and definitely not `O(1)` in behavior. It is also very slow, perhaps due to the use of `std::function` - although I agree this was not one of the question requirements.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Moving a vector is two pointer assignments, that's the whole point of move

Comment: @HenriqueBucher The lookup should be O(1). The slowest will be the first call where the static table is initialised

Comment: if you are moving the vector then you will be destroying it and will have to be reconstructed. That is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as a reference. Ends up it is not necessary to use virtual inheritance since all functions conform to the same signature at the translation level. Only an array of function pointers is necessary.

We start by creating a switch object with a size as template parameter. This size MAXARGS needs to be provided as a macro definition to the compiler command line.

```cpp
double callfn(void* fn, const std::vector<double>& args) {
    static Switch<MAXARGS> sw;
    return sw.fn[args.size()](fn, args.data());
}
```

The Switch object holds an array of function pointers each one responsible for one call with a specific number of arguments. We use some folding expressions trickery to initialize all elements of this array. Using folding expressions allows us to have the loop variable `Is` as a constant at compile time. However this will hit clang's limit of 256 for brackets expansion and you will need to provide `-fbracket-depth=N` greater than MAXARGS. GCC does not seem to have this limit or it is much higher.

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
struct Switch {
    std::array<CallType, N> fn;
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    static void init(std::index_sequence<Is...> s,
                        std::array<CallType, N>& fn) {
        ((fn[Is] = &execute<Is>), ...);
    }
    Switch() {
        init(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, fn);
    }
};
```

Then we use an index sequence technique to generate a list of N arguments and define the `execute<N>` function trampoline.

```cpp
typedef double (*CallType)(void* fn, const double* ptr);
template <size_t> using double_t = double;

template <size_t... Is>
double execute(void* fn, const double* args, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using CallTypeN = double (*)(double_t<Is>...);
    return CallTypeN(fn)(args[Is]...);
}

template< size_t N >
double execute( void* fn, const double* args ) {
    return execute( fn, args, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

What execute does is basically take the double from the vector and place it on registers.

```
0000000000403c70 <double fred2::execute<4ul>(void*, double const*)>:
  403c70:       f2 0f 10 06             movsd  (%rsi),%xmm0
  403c74:       f2 0f 10 4e 08          movsd  0x8(%rsi),%xmm1
  403c79:       f2 0f 10 56 10          movsd  0x10(%rsi),%xmm2
  403c7e:       f2 0f 10 5e 18          movsd  0x18(%rsi),%xmm3
  403c83:       ff e7                   jmpq   *%rdi
  403c85:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  403c8c:       00 00 00
  403c8f:       90                      nop
```

The code above ("Fred's solution 2") has minimal setup time and yields roughly zero cycles above no-op.

```bash
StackOverflow::caleth Result:18 Best:56 Median:84 Slowest:7336
Trivial solution      Result:18 Best:27 Median:27 Slowest:867
Fred's solution       Result:18 Best:0 Median:0 Slowest:18592
Fred's solution 2     Result:18 Best:0 Median:0 Slowest:840
```

The entire comparison is available on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/7bh4j39hx

There is also a [lengthier post on Substack](https://lucisqr.substack.com/p/compile-time-arbitrary-switch-case).

Thanks @caleth for the `double_t` insight and the answer above. @PepijinKramer and @n.m. for the folding directions.